# How To Add A Duplicate Key's Value Into A Key:[Value Array] In Perl

Tags: perl, hash, collision

I am trying to add values to arrays in my hash so as to avoid collisions.

Imagine reading in key value pairs like this:

```
my %color_of = (
    apple  => "red",
    orange => "orange",
    apple  => "green",
);
```

How can I append the value for `apple` to an array of values like so?

```
my %color_of = (
    apple  => ["red", "green"],
    orange => "orange",
);
```

Edit: As was suggested a better data structure to create for the collisions is:

```
my %color_of = (
    apple  => ["red", "green"],
    orange => ["orange"],
);
```

This allows for all values to be pushed into a key's array.

Comment: It would be easier to produce `(apple => ["red", "green"], orange => ["orange"])`.

Comment: In your proposed scheme, how do you distinguish between a key with multiple values and a key with a single value, which is an arrayref?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When considering returning values from a SQL query that presented itself like such:

```
[[apple, "red"], [orange, "orange"], [apple, "green"]]
```

I was able to figure out a good solution to this issue, much easier than the commented solutions on my post.

```
my %hash;
foreach my $res (@rs)
{
        push @{$hash{$res->[0]}}, $res->[1];
}
```

Comment: That creates the data structure I was talking about in my comment (`(apple => ["red", "green"], orange => ["orange"])`). So is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes! That was what I was looking for. That's why I provided the example data structure I was looking for in my original question.

Comment: Your example is different; it has `orange => "orange"`, not `orange => ["orange"]`.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I figured after a little bit of trying that it would be easier to make every value an array. Good catch!

Comment: @landesko Which is what people were trying to tell you in the comments…

Comment: I didn't catch that at first, you are absolutely right. However, the first commented post was completely off. Also was looking for a possible example.

Comment: It was not "completely off". It was a link to all kinds of ways to create a hash of arrays, including the one you used: `push @{ $HoA{"flintstones"} }, "wilma", "betty";`

Answer (score 2):

```
my @pairs=(
    apple  => "red",
    orange => "orange",
    apple  => "green",
);
my %color_of;
push @{ $color_of{shift@pairs} }, shift@pairs while @pairs;
@$_==1 and $_=$$_[0] for values %color_of; #one elem arrays becomes scalar

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%color_of);
```

If you dont want to destroy `@pairs`:

```
my %color_of = sub{ my %h; push@{ $h{shift()} }, shift while@_; %h }->(@pairs);
```

Comment: List::MoreUtils natatime could be used as an alternative to your non destructive routine.

Comment: @landesko given your original post, this is the only viable answer thus far.